# Some dependencies not supported by React 18

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, sanity, emotion

I'm currently following a tutorial and it was before react was v18. I tried doing the things I research and even ask chatgpt for help but I still can't install create-next-app without it having compatible issues with the following dependencies. Please help me install the dependencies with create-next-app. Also can I ask if @mui/system is the alternative for @mui/styles in react v18? if not, are there any? thank you

```
   {
      "name": "my-app",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
        "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.1",
        "@mui/material": "^5.4.1",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.4.1",
        "next": "12.0.10",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "8.9.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "12.0.10"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.14",
    "next": "13.2.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
```

Alternatively, you may want to run the npm command to install dependencies instead fiddling with the entries in the file. Try this:

`npm install @mui/system @emotion/react @emotion/styled @mui/icons-material @emotion/server @emotion/css`

According to the [@mui/styles](https://mui.com/system/styles/basics/) page, @mui/system is the "recommended alternative" for @mui/styles, since @mui/styles was a "legacy styling solution" and was deprecated in Material UI v5.